# Headlight issues with 2009 Camry

Tags: toyota, headlight, camry

The problem Im having with my 09 Camry is super dim low beams. The high beams work great but can't even see 10 feet ahead with lows. Fuses aren't blown and so far I've changed the housings the bulbs and the switch on the steering wheel. Running out of parts to swap lol any ideas?

Comment: Have you measured the voltage across the bulbs while they are switched on? Measure the voltage across the low and high beams as a comparison.

Comment: In addition to comparing voltages between low and high beams, try measuring each low beam connection to chassis ground. One pin should be at least 12v while the other is ground. If 12v is on one pin then check ground continuity from the other pin to ground. If 12v is on one pin, connect this pin to the low beam lamp and use a length of wire to connect other lamp connection to chassis ground. Wires to each low beam may be corroded and/or damaged under insulation or at connectors.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2009 Camry Hybrid and have the candle power issue with low beam headlights.  Since I live in a cold climate(Wisconsin), when the temp is 20 degrees or lower, I have to jump start the battery from the trunk to start the car.  This battery is the output for the electrical box next to the battery that regulates the lights.  I needed to replace this battery to fix the headlight issue.